# How to get json output from php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api

This is my PHP code for json output:

```
    $sql="SELECT id,name FROM languages ORDER BY id";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    // Fetch all
    $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $out_put = json_encode($result);
    echo $out_put;
```

This is the json output of the above php code:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "English"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Kanada"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Hindi"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Telugu"
    }
}
```

But I want output like this:

```
{
 "Responsecode":200,
 "Message":"Sucess",
 "languagelist": [
   {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "English"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "Kannada"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "name": "Hindi"
   },
   {
     "id": "4",
     "name": "Telugu"
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to create API and I am new in it. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just ad in top of the code 

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @DevsiOdedra That is not going to add the 2 new items into op's array now is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

```
$out_put = json_encode([
   "Responsecode" => 200,
   "Message" => "Sucess",
   "languagelist" => $result
]);
```

Comment: what happen if query give no record

Comment: Of course you are right. So as @DevsiOdedra about header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
$output['Responsecode'] = 200;
$output['Message'] = "Sucess";
$output['languagelist'] = $result;
$out_put = json_encode($output);
```